# retrieve android version name from manifest file using power shell

Tags: perl, powershell, batch-file

I am working on android project and i want to retrieve the  android version name from manifest file using power shell or perl command. here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest android:versionCode="27" android:versionName="1.0.1.42" package="com.shure.motiv" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

my android version name is 1.0.1.42. How do i retrieve the 1.0.1.42 and set as the environment variable. Please can you anyone help me on the same.

Comment: There is no file. And show some effort and the code with which you had problems

Comment: @guiwhatsthat It wasn't properly formatted as `code` and then wasn't shown at all because it is <xml> and rendered as nothing.

Comment: here is my manifest file content

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest android:versionCode="27" android:versionName="1.0.1.42" package="com.shure.motiv" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Read the xml file with get-content and search for the part which you want to change with xpath

Comment: Please can you write the code i am totally new to power shell

Comment: Thats not how Stackoverflow works. This a simple task. Google it and you will find a solution

Comment: @krishna, use perl or a batch file instead if you don't know or are new to powershell. Why did you ask for powershell help if you don't know it?

Comment: Thanks, I searched for the solution but no luck, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344179/how-to-get-value-from-xml-by-powershell  this is similler but not work for me.

Comment: [tag:batch-file] doesn't mean processing a lot of files.

Comment: @SteveFest Yes, it rather means processing (a lot of) commands, possibly on a set of files. But who said any different?

Comment: You&#39;re kinda wrong. Batch file is a kind of Windows script. It does help to process multiple files, but unrelated to the scenario

Answer (score 0):

A batch file which uses powershell may cover two of your tagged options:

```
@For /F %%A In ('Powershell -C "[xml]$fC=Get-Content 'AndroidManifest.xml';"^
 "$fC.manifest.versionName"') Do @Set "versionName=%%A"
@Echo %versionName%
@Pause
```

*Please note, that because you've made absolutely no attempt to create any code, no tutoring will be entered into with reference to the above.*