# obtaining information from xml file via power shell in an attempt to uninstall application

Tags: xml, powershell

I have been having an issue with parsing an xml file

```
<DisplayName>Remote_Take_Over_S1_0002</DisplayName>
```

I am trying to get the above information from `"C:\ProgramData\App-V\1BBEDDA5-595E-4CF7-834A-B282C4981469\0C71FE9F-F1C0-47F9-9518-E94898B6424F\AppxManifest.xml"`

I have know idea how or where to start but i have got this far.

```
            $ComputerName = $txb_hostname.Text

        $RemoteParentPath = Join-Path -Path "\\$ComputerName" -ChildPath 'c$\ProgramData\App-V'

        $RemoteManifestPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $RemoteParentPath -Recurse -Filter 'AppxManifest.xml' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

        foreach ($manifestFile in $RemoteManifestPaths)
        {
             $xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $manifestFile -Raw)
             $xml.SelectSingleNode('//*[local-name()="DisplayName"]/text()').Value 
             LogWrite $xml
        }
```

Any Ideas?

Errors now 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:6 char:5

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'H:\AppxManifest.xml' because it does not exist.
At line:5 char:18

Managed to sort above errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Value from xml by PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344179/how-to-get-value-from-xml-by-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looking to find all `AppxManifest.xml` files under the `c:\ProgramData\App-V` path on the remote computer (or in this case, the current computer using a UNC path to the file), then manipulate that XML file in some way; maybe to fetch the `DisplayName` value?

If so, try something like this:

```
[string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
[string]$RemoteParentPath = Join-Path -Path "\\$ComputerName" -ChildPath 'c$\ProgramData\App-V'
[string[]]$RemoteManifestPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $RemoteParentPath -Recurse -Filter 'AppxManifest.xml' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
foreach ($manifestFile in $RemoteManifestPaths) {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $manifestFile -Raw)
    $xml.SelectSingleNode('//DisplayName/text()').Value
}
```

I've broken it down into multiple lines to make it easier to understand what's going on / try out each piece.  NB: I've not tested the code itself.

Comment: Keeps stating 

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:6 char:5

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'H:\AppxManifest.xml' because it does not exist.
At line:5 char:18

Comment: Hmm, looks like I'd missed the opening brace for the for loop (now fixed), but that doesn't explain why it would be using your H drive...   Are you amending this code before running it?

Comment: Ah sorry - just realised I was only returning file names, not paths (as converting to strings... amended)

Comment: I'm not sure either why it is pointing to my h drive the script isn't located their might be because I need to change directory from my h when I was working on something their earlier I'll check tomorrow, I notic d the brace was missing I'll check the code tomorrow to see if it runs

Comment: it brings back "version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" Package" which is the top line of the XML file do you know of a way to get DisplayName which would be line 10 in the XML file

Comment: Are you running exactly the code given above?  `$xml.SelectSingleNode('//DisplayName/text()').Value` says to find the text value of the first DisplayName element found in the XML.

Comment: ps. If there's a schema involved, use `$xml.SelectSingleNode('//*[local-name()="DisplayName"]/text()').Value` (there are ways to load the name table with the appropriate namespaces and query with a prefixed name, but for now the above is enough).  My guess is that you're just looking at the value of `$xml` itself, and you're seeing it formatted as a table, rather than the XML (i..e `$xml.OuterXml`.

Comment: I have put the newer code up it just keeps bringing back xml                            Package
---                            -------
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" Package
Remote_Take_Over_S1_0004
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" Package
Directories_S1_0004
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" Package
EARS_S1_0001
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" Package
NotepadPlusPlus_S1_0001
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" Package

Comment: I just saw your edit `LogWrite $xml`.  I don't know what `LogWrite` does, but I think you probably wanted to do `LogWrite $xml.SelectSingleNode('//DisplayName/text()').Value`; i.e. as that's the piece that pulls the display name value from the XML.

Comment: So I have a text box I write my outputs to so for example logwrite $CPU would write whatever $CPU has stored in the variable hopefully this makes sense

Comment: That brings back the text on its own, which is what i was looking for. once it tries to write it to the textbox using logwrite it shows blank. i guess ill investigate that now thank you